# cronjob find and remove folders and files in subfolder

Tags: linux, cron, find, exec, rm

I am looking for a way to find an delete files within a subfolder. The folder structure is as follows:

- mainfolder/station1/archive
- mainfolder/station2/archive
- mainfolder/station3/archive
- ...

and I want to delete all folders and files older then 10 days within the archive folder using a cronjob.
I know that I can use

```
@daily  /usr/bin/find /path/to/mainfolder -mtime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

to delete all files/folders within mainfolder. I also know, that I can run

```
rm -rf */archive/*
```

from mainfolder to delete them manually but I can't manage to combine these two. I tried something like

```
/usr/bin/find /path/to/mainfolder -exec rm -rf {}\*/archive/\* \;
```

which didn't work. Is the combination of find and rm the correct way or is it better to write a small script to perform the action?

Comment: `man find` will show  you several options, like `-name archive -type d` . Not really a programming Q as StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , or [unix.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions. AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.